# Posting links in classified ads website in 2020?

Tags: seo

Regardless of any other parameter, does posting ads with a link to my site on a classified ads website will still help with referencing nowadays? Or are these types of backlinks filtered by search engines?

Answer (score 1):

Ad backlinks typically use `rel=nofollow` to prevent the host website from implying an endorsement (and thus sharing any link juice) with the advertiser.

If you find an ad site that lets you place an ad without `rel=nofollow`, I would still be leery of the potential benefit, since that site likely has a lot of outgoing links to sites of questionable quality, and Google knows this and will probably reduce the SEO weight of those links.